# Non-standard ternary expression objective c

Tags: objective-c

I've been reading through an objective-c method, but I read something that bothered my mind.

I'm used to ternary expressions, I use them quite a lot but I don't know if this is one or not ?

```
- (void)updateDocSizeIndicator
{
    NSLog(@"REPRO : WindowController - updateDocSizeIndicator");
    int nbPages = [documentView.subviews count];
    [documentSizeIndicator setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"/ %d %@", nil), nbPages ? nbPages : 1, nbPages > 1 ? @"pages" : @"page"]];
}
```

That last line is my problem, I don't understand the use of the ',' in this ternary. Could someone explain it to me please ?

```
[documentSizeIndicator setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"/ %d %@", nil), nbPages ? nbPages : 1, nbPages > 1 ? @"pages" : @"page"]];
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are **two** different ternary expressions, one for each of the two last arguments to `NSLocalizedString()`. The first evaluates to an integer while the second evaluates to a string.

Comment: What makes you think that this is "non-standard"? Both the conditional operator and the comma separator for function arguments are standard C, so is their usage presented here.

Comment: I called it a non-standard because I was not used to this. I usually use them as a var = (condition) ? true : false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you have a complex expression that is built from many expressions.

```
[documentSizeIndicator setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"/ %d %@", nil), nbPages ? nbPages : 1, nbPages > 1 ? @"pages" : @"page"]];
```

We can simplify that. Obviously there is a method `-setStringValue:` (BTW: You could use dot notation for this) taking one single argument:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"/ %d %@", nil), nbPages ? nbPages : 1, nbPages > 1 ? @"pages" : @"page"];
dosumentSizeIndicator.stringValue = stringValue;
```

Let's focus on the first line. There is a message with the selector `stringWithFormat:`. You have a corresponding method `-stringWithFormat:…` that has an open parameter list: You can pass as many arguments as you want. Each argument is separated with a comma:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"/ %d %@", nil), nbPages ? nbPages : 1, nbPages > 1 ? @"pages" : @"page"
--argument1-----------------------, --argument2----------, --argument3---------------------
```

For every argument you have an expression (well, you have to):

```
argument1 = NSLocalizedString(@"/ %d %@", nil) // a function call
argument2 = nbPages ? nbPages : 1              // a conditional expression
argument3 = nbPages > 1 ? @"pages" : @"page"   // a conditional expression
```

Therefore the commas are not part of the expressions, but separate them.

Answer (score 1):

This can be broken down as follows:

```
[documentSizeIndicator setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:
        NSLocalizedString(@"/ %d %@", nil), 
            nbPages ? nbPages : 1, 
            nbPages > 1 ? @"pages" : @"page"]];
```

The call to `NSLocalizedString(@"/ %d %@", nil)` is passing the string `@"/ %d %@"` as the bundle lookup key and no comment (parameter) - see the [Foundations docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/). The key itself must be defined in the Localizable.strings file that defines the default values (see [this internationalization tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014). The resulting value must resemble the key used and provide a format string for a decimal and object (e.g. maybe just the same value as the key used by default - `@"/ %d %@"`).

So, the result of calling the above `NSLocalizedString` would be something like `NSString` `@"/ %d %@"`.

The rest of the line is just providing the values to populate that format. As @cyclone stated, you have two ternary operators, used to populate the format:
    nbPages ? nbPages : 1
    nbPages > 1 ? @"pages" : @"page"